# Find and replace all instances of $\frac{d}{dx}$

Tags: lyx, find

According to ISO 80000-2, the d's in d/dx should actually be in upright Roman font.

So, to conform to these standards, I want to replace all such (math mode, italicized) d's in my document with upright Roman d's. (I am using LyX so ideally any solution should cater to that.)

That is, change something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\frac{dz}{dx}$
$\frac{dy}{dx}$
$\frac{d\sin x}{dx}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

To this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}x}$
$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$
$\frac{\mathrm{d}\sin x}{\mathrm{d}x}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I do this automatically/fairly quickly (instead of manually changing every "d")? Assume I have a very large document with lots of d's everywhere, both in math and text mode, so I can't just do a Replace All.

I've tried using LyX's Advanced Find and Replace function but this doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Does LyX support regular expression searches? If yes, it should be pretty straightforward. In my editor one would have to replace "\\frac\{d([^\[]*)\}\{d(.*)" by "\\frac\{\\mathrm\{d\}\1\}\{\\mathrm\{d\}\2", but the precise syntax may differ.

Comment: @marmot: Yes it seems like it does. In Advanced Find and Replace, I can Insert Regular Expression. But I'm not sure what to do next. I just tried your suggestion but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Do you want to replace it in the source file or do you want the replacement to happen *on the fly* when you process the file with LaTeX?

Comment: @HenriMenke: I'm not sure what the difference is. I'm going to say that ideally I want to changes to be in the source file too, but what really matters is that my output PDF displays the intended result.

Comment: This is not an answer to your search and replace problem. Why not use the physics package to typeset derivatives? It would be very simple like \dv{\sin x}{x}, \dv[2]{y}{x}.

Comment: @mas: I don't think that's supported in LyX.

Comment: I do not use LyX, so take my reply with a pinch of salt :-) Using a package should have nothing to do with LyX.

Comment: @mas: It won't appear as WYSIWYG. Which is one of the chief advantages of LyX.

Comment: Well, I am sorry, I don't have Lyx installed. All I can do is to tell you that my above search tries to find `\frac{d` followed by an arbitrary number of characters not equal to `}`, which get stored then in `\1`, followed by `}{d`. These things then get replaced by `\frac{\mathrm{d}\1}{\mathrm{d}`. The `\2` thing was not necessary. All this will break of course if there are spaces between `{` and `d`, but one could generalize the regex to cover this as well.

Comment: Note that LyX stores math as raw LaTeX, I believe, in the .lyx file. So you could open the the .lyx file and use a regex in your text editor, if the LyX regex is not working.